# How to find app service that an outgoing IP address belongs to?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an IP address that I know belongs to one of the app services on Azure. How can I find out which app service is it?

**UPDATE**

Kaushal Kumar Panday's answer reveals IP Addresses on Azure do not belong to a single app service, but belong to a data centre.

Is there any way to get a list of app services in an Azure account that share an outgoing IP Address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Azure App Service**, the **Outbound IP Address** do not correspond to any specific Web App. They are tied to the data centre and shared by all the apps on that data centre.

So all the sites running on that specific data centre will have the same **Outbound IP Address**.

There is no way to trace back to the web app using the IP. You may be able to trace it back to the specific data centre, but not the originating web app.

**UPDATE**

Your site on the same data centre can have different list of Outbound IP Addresses. A data centre is a logical unit, which is comprised of several physical units. For example, **West Europe** is a logical entity which is comprised of several physical data centres. This approach is used to scale the data centres. See this article: [Inside Azure App Service Architecutre](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt793270.aspx)

[image: Scale Units]

On one scale unit (physical DC) several thousands of sites are running and you might be seeing the Outbound IP address of that specific scale unit.

Also, if you have all the apps inside the same app service plan, then their Outbound IP Address will always be the same.

If you ping the default name of the web app you will know the actual scale unit as shown below

[image: Cmd]

Comment: Are you sure about this? All our app services on the same data centre have 4-5 distinct IP addresses, I've never seen two sharing the same addresses.

Comment: you are seeing a logical view of the data centre. physically, there are more than 1 data centres. I am adding it to the answer.

Comment: You can ping the app service in the same data centre and you will see different digits which correspond to different scale units in the same data centre.

Comment: Kaushal Kumar Panday this is a great answer, I get it know, thanks. And do you think there would be any way to get a list of app services that use a particular ip address and belong to an Azure account of our own?

Comment: Yea there is one thing that you could try. You can pick up one web app, say **A** and determine its list of Outbound IP Addresses. This list will be same for all the other web app's which are part of the App Service Plan as **A**. Apart from this there is no easy way.

Answer (score 1):

This might help for others, but if you go into your app service and choose **Properties** you will see the **Outbound IP Addresses** and additional outbound ip addresses of that particular app service.  It's a list of IPs, not just one.  Pinging your service will not give you the IP you're looking for as that is your inbound IP address.

[image: properties under app service blade]

I can confirm that for the last 6 months, our IP address list hasn't changed.  I know these are shared, which for some might be a security issue, so beware when opening a firewall rule.

[image]